# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation deprecated, but don't understand viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm porting my iPad app to iOS8 and Swift.

In portrait, i use a root UIViewController and when the de device is rotated to landscape, I segue to another UIViewController. I've come up with 2 solutions, one based on UIDevice notifications and the other on `willRotateToInterfaceRotation`. I alway try to stay away from the Observer pattern, it's just a habit of me.

The Observer works fine, but the override in both UIViewController of 
func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval)
looks cleaner to my eyes ;)

But now in iOS8 that function is deprecated and I should use

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

But I don't have any idea how I can work with that to get the same result.

This is the `rootViewController`:

```
      override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(
                     toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, 
                                   duration: NSTimeInterval) {

      if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||                     
         toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight) {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLandscape", sender: self)

      }

    }
```

and the `UIViewControllerLanscape`:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(
             toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, 
                           duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || 
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {

        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,
                                                               completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I don't like to use deprecated functions, so I'm in doubt what to do...go for the observer or what??

This is the code I use when (only) the root UIViewController is an observer of the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    let dev = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    dev.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: dev) 
 }

 func orientationChanged(note: NSNotification) -> () {
    if let uidevice: UIDevice = note.object? as? UIDevice {

        switch uidevice.orientation {
        case .LandscapeLeft, .LandscapeRight:
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLandscape", sender: self)
        default:
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I really like your ideas on how to make a solution for these deprecated functions. It's a total mystery to me....or maybe the Observer is the better solution now. Please share your ideas.

Regards,

jr00n